# Loop through a repeater client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net-3.5

how to loop through a repeater client side when page has a masterpage?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The repeater only exists server side, it doesn't render any HTML code for itself. It only render it's contents, so there is nothing that you can target on the client side.

If you have an element in the template that has a specific name or class, you can target those elements in the client script.